# Explanation of Javascript nested loop script

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I am having trouble understanding this nested loop and how it works.

```js
function foo() { 
    function bar(a) { 
        i = 2; // change value of in in enclosing scope
        console.log(a + i);
    } 
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) { 
        bar(i); // infinite loop
    } 
}
foo();
```

Can someone explain why is bar called with 3? I thought first time bar is called it would be zero from inital value of i in the enclosing for loop?

I know this is an infinite loop where a + i always prints 5
I know that the  value of parameter a passed to bar is always 3
I know that the value of i in function bar is always 2

Can someone walk me through one repeitition of this infinite loop, explaining the order in which things occur.

Answer (score 0):

It is a infinite loop because `i` is declare with `var` so it remain at the top of `foo` function and then `bar` function modify the same `i`. So `i` will be values 0, 2, 3, 2, 3...

```js
function foo() {
    function bar(a) {
        i = 2; // change value of in in enclosing scope
        //console.log(a + i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(i);// always 0, 3, 3....
        bar(i); // infinite loop
        //console.log(i);// always 2
    }
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the reason why it steps in an infinite loop is because of 'var', `i = 2` gets hoisted at the top and whenever the for loop iterates `i` is reassigned the value 2, therefore a never ending loop.